# Is it always better to using stacked LSTM than single LSTM?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm, rnn, machine-learning-model

I am currently studying LSTM and RNNs.

I came across several concepts like [Multidimensional LSTM](https://medium.com/@stefanshi1988/use-multidimensional-lstm-network-to-learn-linear-and-non-linear-mapping-e7692482fe12) and [Stacked LSTM](https://machinelearningmastery.com/stacked-long-short-term-memory-networks/).

I have used Stacked LSTM and it gives me a better performance than single LSTM. As per my understanding, if I increase the depth of LSTM, the number of hidden units also increases. It means overfitting, right? Then why am I getting better results?

[Note: I have used `BatchNorm` and `Dropout` after every stack of LSTM ]

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you can indeed consider adding more layers and batchnorm/dropout to a neural network a means for controlling bias and variance of your model, respectively. However, increasing variance by stacking more layers doesn't always at all mean that you overfit your model.

To diagnose that you are actually overfitting you should see that your training loss is much lower than your validation loss (image below).
[image]

But as a general rule, you should aim for minimising that "gap" between your training and validation loss curves. This gap, aka generalisation gap appears to be getting minimised in your case with adding more layers (see ideal below). And that is absolutely fair.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

From https://machinelearningmastery.com/stacked-long-short-term-memory-networks/:

"Stacking LSTM hidden layers makes the model deeper, more accurately earning the description as a deep learning technique ... The additional hidden layers are understood to recombine the learned representation from prior layers and create new representations at high levels of abstraction. For example, from lines to shapes to objects ... A sufficiently large single hidden layer Multilayer Perceptron can be used to approximate most functions. Increasing the depth of the network provides an alternate solution that requires fewer neurons and trains faster. Ultimately, adding depth it is a type of representational optimization."

Increasing the number of layers/hidden units in a neural network doesn't necessarily result in overfitting. Too few will result in low training and test accuracies; too many will result in high training accuracy but low test accuracy (overfitting). Somewhere in the middle there will be the right amount of hidden layers and units for the problem. Some complex problems like NLP require a number of stacked hidden LSTM layers http://ruder.io/deep-learning-nlp-best-practices/.

This thread might be useful: https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/3156/how-to-select-number-of-hidden-layers-and-number-of-memory-cells-in-an-lstm